# Adjust iPhone audio input gain / sensitivity

Tags: iphone, input, volume, microphone

I am creating an application which incorporates a sound level meter (the user wears a contact or throat microphone).
I am using the (deprecated) custom class [SCListener](http://www.stephencelis.com/2009/03/02/now-i-just-need-an-audience.html) which uses an `AudioQueue` and retrieves the value `kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter` which is a value between 0 and 1.

My issue is that at normal usage levels, the `kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter` value is already peaked at 1.0 - what I am hoping to do is *dampen* or reduce the input sensitivity of the contact microphone, so that a scream or really loud yelling registers as a 1.0 instead of regular talking.

Through my searching I have seen some discussion of Audio Units, but have not found any documentation or examples that I have been able to understand.

Is there a way I can reduce the sensitivity or gain or the input line in my application? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There currently appears to be no public API to manually adjust the mic input gain on iOS devices.

Alternatively, you could set up an Audio Queue or RemoteIO Audio Unit, analyze the PCM samples you find in the callback buffers, and compute your own amplitude envelopes (or spectrally weighted amplitudes, etc.) and scale however you wish.  But that's after the mic input sampling.

Comment: Would this allow me to measure a greater input volume than the max using kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter or an AVAudioRecorder peakValue, or would it effectively be the same? (i.e. would the input level already be maxed out before I analyze the PCM samples)?